# Why is Apache Tomcat Hosting always more expensive than other kinds of hosting?

Tags: web-hosting

I've looked around, and it always appears that Tomcat hosting is more rare and expensive than other kinds of hosting, why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Because the skills needed to maintain it aren't as common as, say, Apache. So you need to pay the support people more and the cost gets added onto the hosting.